# include raw html in shiny dashboard break the styling

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm building a shiny app with shiny dashboard. I'm accessing a website with its API. If the provided user name and password are not correct, the response will be a html error page text.

`<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.32 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 403 - Invalid login or missing privilege.</h1><HR size=\"1\" noshade=\"noshade\"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Invalid login or missing privilege.</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>Access to the specified resource (Invalid login or missing privilege.) has been forbidden.</u>...`

If the access is successful, the response will be a csv.

Because there could be multiple cases of errors, instead of checking every error page and show some error message, I want to render the error page in app directly, which will provide most accurate information.

I rendered the response text like this:

`output$response <- renderUI(HTML(res_cont))`

However that will break the styling of whole app, probably because there is some global styles in the html page.

How can I prevent this happen? One fall back solution is just strip the style in the html response. Though I want to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Please structure this to help us understand what you want.

Comment: What kind of structure do you mean? The ideal solution will be a reproducible example, but to create that kind of example need quite some efforts. I'm hoping somebody have similar experience or in depth knowledge can give some hints just based on these descriptions.

Comment: The key problem is that when I render a html object inside shiny dashboard UI, the html object style conflict with the style of shiny dashboard. This is understandable but I want to know if there is some alternative solutions.

Comment: You could include the error page inside of an iframe. That will contain each page's styles.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that after I posted the question. Will try it and report the result.

Comment: It turned out `iframe` in shiny is more complex than I thought. I have the html document in string but cannot get it rendered, maybe because of escaping. I tried parse the html correctly but still cannot get it right. At last I decided just use the response status code instead.